# How do I change the line height of a GtkTreeView using gtkrc?

Tags: gtk

In a Gtk application, I have that line height:

[image: GtkTreeView narrow]

and I want this line height:

[image: GtkTreeView wide]

Note that this is the same font size.

Is it possible to achieve this line height / padding using gtkrc? How?

Any hint will be appreciated.

fbmd

Answer (score 1):

Add to gtkrc:

```
style "tree" {
  GtkTreeView::vertical-separator = 8
}
class "GtkTreeView" style "tree"
```

Comment: This works most of the time, thanks, but it does not seem to affect all TreeViews, some stay as they were before. DO you have a hint for that behaviour?